# How can i generate rtp pcap file with silk codec?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, rtp, silk

for a university project my teacher said me generate rtp pcap file with silk codec.
I explorer ffmpeg and i dont see any thing useful for me for generate rtp pcap file with encode silk codec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For generate pcap silk codec you can use:

Silk 24 KHz -----> old version of Baresip

Silk 8 KHz and Silk 12 KHz and Silk 16 KHz and Silk 24 KHz ----> old Version of microsip(microsip use pjsua2 )

Silk 8 KHz and Silk 12 KHz and Silk 16 KHz and Silk 24 KHz ---->  java application windows Jitsi